# Typescript output filename change

Tags: typescript

I'm outputting my typescript project to single js files but want to change the name of the output files to filename.debug.js instead of filename.js. Is this possible.

This *.debug.js files then go through a minimizer and get outputted to *.js

Using TS with VS 2012.

Thanks

Donal

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while but, did you found a way to do it?
I'm trying to do the same right now and I'm kind of lost

Thanks!

Comment: Nope... but have not looked for a solution in a long time...

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in the in the csproj file. In there you find some TypeScript tags (For example TypeScriptTarget, TypeScriptModuleKind).
Just put the following there:

```
<TypeScriptOutFile>test.debug.js</TypeScriptOutFile>
```

Make sure you put it in the right place for debug/release configurations.

For vs2013 users, you can just go to the project properties page and there you find the "TypeScript Build" tab on the left. There you find the option: Combine Javascript output (which adds the above xml)

Comment: Hi Dick, thanks for the quick response... this outputs all ts to a single .debug.js file - however is there a way to get the ts compiler to output each .ts file to a corresponding .debug.js file. I want a 1 to 1 mapping of ts to js files.

Thanks